# Publish the results from XML Viewer as RSS?

Tags: 2010, rss

I have an XML Viewer web part that consumes an RSS feed and displays the results on a site page.

Now I would like to publish these results as an RSS feed from my site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consume or aggregate RSS feed data and then expose it as an RSS feed itself, you need to write a custom page and do it with code - you will not be able to do this with out of box Web Parts. The CQWP provides the ability to expose itself as an RSS Feed, but it can only aggregate SharePoint List data.

Comment: +1 for providing value recognized by the original poster. Thinking creatively beyond your suggestion, do you think a combination of an external list and a CQWP would do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add in a content editor web part right below your XML web part.  Add a cool RSS image from the internet, and make it hyperlink with the original RSS feed URL.  It seems like bad karma trying to rip off someone else's RSS feed and trying to pass it off as your own.

Comment: The links and author information from the original RSS feed will remain in the re-published feed unless it is being re-written - but yes, if it is - BAD!!!

Comment: The original feed belongs to me. However, publishing it directly is not an option.